# Using workbox, redirect from o-auth navigates to the service-worker.js file rather than base url

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker, workbox

I have an Create React APP application that redirects to an auth flow when a user hits my application url (e.g. https://myapp/) without auth headers. I can get everything working as expected except that once the service-worker is active the redirect from the auth flow to `https://myapp/` rather navigates to `https://myapp/service-worker.js`.

The default CRA workbox-sw setup wasn't working with this (because credentials are not included by default and redirects are not set to `follow` or `manual`) so I created my own custom service-worker. I have tried so many different variations of explicit routes to whitelists and blacklists, most of which resulted in the browser refusing to show the corrupted page (Redirected response while RedirectMode is not "follow"). My final, "working" solution was to interfere as little as possible:

```js
if ('function' === typeof importScripts) {
  importScripts(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.5.0/workbox-sw.js'
  );

  /* global workbox */
  if (workbox) {
    /* injection point for manifest files.  */
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|ico)$/,
      new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'images',
        plugins: [
          new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 60,
            maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 Days
          })
        ]
      })
    );


    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      /^https:\/\/myapp\/api\/latest\/\w*\/?$/,
      new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'apiRequests',
        fetchOptions: {
          credentials: 'include'
        },
        plugins: [
          // only cache for 1 year
          new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24
          })
        ]
      })
    );

  } else {
    console.log('Workbox could not be loaded. No Offline support');
  }
}
```

The result of this is that I end up, after returning to the site and logging in, seeing my service-worker.js in the browser. I would have hoped to have seen my index.html... I tried renaming the `service-worker.js` to test that it was definitely the fact that it was the service-worker and not the file name that was pertinent - it is the sw. This makes me think it is to do with the service-worker lifecycle, but this cannot be the expected result of that!

I have hacked around this, but the hack makes me sad, so any help would be appreciated!

Here is the hack:

```js
//service-worker.js
const cleanResponse = async({
  url,
  event,
  params
}) => {
  try {
    // By default the service worker is being navigated to, so we need to force it here
    if (/service-worker-custom.js$/.test(url)) {
      return fetch(
        new Request('/index.html', {
          redirect: 'manual',
          credentials: 'include'
        })
      );
    }
    return fetch(
      new Request(event.request, {
        redirect: 'manual',
        credentials: 'include'
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return fetch(new Request('/index.html'));
  }
};

// Always go to network for navigation
// By default the service worker is being navigated to, so we need to force it here
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({
    event
  }) => event.request.mode === 'navigate',
  cleanResponse
);
```

and in my application I then have to clear that navigation